# "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices" - I am trying to import my data into SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, tuples

I am trying to insert my data that is being pulled from yfinance in csv format to SQL server. I am getting the error "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list" - How can I fix up my code? I've tried using sqlite3 but that never seems to work for me. This version worked for my other scripts in inserting data to my sql server, but for this particular combined csv, I am getting this error. How can I fix up my code?

```
import yfinance as yf
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Empyz\Desktop")






list1=['2022-03-18', '2022-03-25', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-08', '2022-04-14', '2022-04-22', '2022-05-20', '2022-06-17', '2022-07-15', '2022-10-21', '2023-01-20', '2024-01-19']

gme = yf.Ticker("gme")

for date in list1:
    df = gme.option_chain(date)
    df_call = df[0]
    df_put = df[1]
    
    #outputs options data to csv based on dates and type
    df_call.to_csv(f'C:\Empyz\Deskop\\call_{date}.csv', index=False)
    df_put.to_csv(f'C:\Empyz\Deskop\\put_{date}.csv', index=False)        

extension = 'csv'
#all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob(f'*.{extension}')]

#combine all files in the list
combined_pd = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_pd.to_csv( "Options_Data_Combined.csv", index=False)
print(combined_pd)


"""
Step 2 Specify columns we want to import
"""

columns = ['contractSymbol','lastTradeDate' ,'strike' ,'lastPrice' ,'bid' ,'ask' ,'change' ,'percentChange' ,'volume' ,'openInterest' ,'impliedVolatility' ,'inTheMoney' ,'contractSize','currency']

df_data = df[columns]
records = df_data.values.tolist()
    

"""
Step 3 Create database connection instance and connect to SQL Server
"""
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=localhost;'
                      'Database=Stocks;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
print('Connected Successfully to SQL Server')

"""
Step 4 Truncate (remove all data) from your table before inserting new records from your .csv file
"""
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE [Options_Data_GME]")
cursor.commit();
cursor.close()
print('SuccessfullyTRUNCATED TABLE [Options_Data_GME]')
    
  

"""
Step 4 Create a cursor connection and insert records
"""
sql_insert = '''
    INSERT INTO [Options_Data_GME] 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)
'''



try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(sql_insert, records)
    cursor.commit();    
#except Exception as e:
    cursor.rollback()
   # print(str(e[1]))
finally:
    print('Successfully inserted data into table [Options_Data_GME].')
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: SQL Server <> SSMS (SQL Server **Management Studio**). SSMS is an IDE like application which is specifically design *for* SQL Server, but it is *not* SQL Server. You aren't importing your data into SSMS, and SSMS actually has nothing to do with the problem here. SQL Server your Database Engine.

Comment: How can I update the code to import into my SSMS database? The importing into my SSMS works for other scripts, but for this particular dataset, it gives me the tuples error and I'm not sure how to fox it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) database, as I just stated.

Comment: Gotcha, but how can I insert the data into my local database then? I have multiple scripts that are already doing so, but this particular one is giving me errors

Comment: This seems like a Pandas error, not SQL Server-related. What line throws the error message?

Comment: Hi - @AlwaysLearning -  Is there any easy way to identify the line that throws the error? I am using Spyder, and it doesn't seem to specify the line number... I did however run the code in small sections, and the error popped up on the line starting with "df_data = df[columns]"